# Natty Narwhal slowed my operating speed way down

Tags: 12.04

I'm using a toshiba satellite w/ a GenuineIntel T1350 @ 1.86GHz & 72GB HD - running lucid lynx & runs great; tried to upgrade to natty narwhal, but slowed operating speed so much, reinstalled natty (10.04) again.

12.04 is listed to need only 512MB and 2GB processor - will 12.04 run smoothly on my ancient laptop?  Any experiences/advice out there?  Thanks.

Comment: I also had bizarre slowdowns in 11.04, on a more modern hardware. For example, package upgrade takes ages, compared to either 10.04 or 12.04. I never figured out why. Try the 12.04 livecd (or 12.10 beta if you're adventurous) and see if it performs better.

Answer (score 2):

If you think 12.04 runs too slow, I suggest you run a flavor of Ubuntu more suited to slower computers. My personal favorite is [Linux Mint XFCE](http://linuxmint.com/rel_maya_xfce_whatsnew.php), it's based on Ubuntu so you'll feel right at home even though it looks slightly different. It comes with a bunch of neat stuff included that are not included in Ubuntu by default, such as Java, non-free codecs and Flash.

If you really don't want to move outside the Ubuntu family, there's also [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/). Basically, I suggest you should try running a distro that has [XFCE](http://xfce.org/) as a desktop environment, which both of the previously mentioned do.